# Existence of a positive solution to a linear system Ax=b when b is not fixed

Tags: matrix-equations

I'm interested in the existence of a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n, +}$ such that for a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{mxn} $ and a vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^m $, $Mx=b$.  I've already looked into Farkas' Lemma but that assumes a fixed $M$ and $b$.  The only constraint I place on $b$ is that the elements in $b$ must follow a particular order, but not that they have specific values.  For example, if $[1, 2, 3]$ is a valid vector $b$ then so is $[1, 1000, 2000]$.

As a more concrete example, consider the matrix 
$$M=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & .5 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and the vector 
$$b_1=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then there does not exist a vector $x$ that solves the equation $Mx=b_1$ such that every element in $x$ is positive.  However, the vector $$b_2=\begin{bmatrix}1.9 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} $$ has solutions $x$ where element is positive. An example is $$x=\begin{bmatrix} .025 \\ .000001 \\ .925  \end{bmatrix}$$

My question is whether there always exists an ordered $b$ such that there exists an $x$ with positive elements.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? If i am understanding correctly, are you trying to solve a bunch of linear equations $Mx=b$ simultaneously?

Comment: No, I only want to solve one.  I have a matrix $M$, and an ordered collection $b$.  However, I'm free to choose the values of $b$ with the constraint that the elements of $b$ retain the same order.  Put differently, I'm not given the values $b$, merely the order of the elements of $b$.

Comment: I've updated the question to include an example.